# How to use mysql command LOAD DATA INFILE with PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Is it possible to use the `mysql` command `LOAD DATA INFILE` as `PreparedStatement`? Because java seems to interpret the `?` placeholder as filename itself.

```
Statement st = con.prepareStatement("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '?'...");

for (file : files) {
  st.setString(1, file.getAbsolutePath()); 
  st.addBatch();
}
st.executeBatch();
```

Result:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
```

Comment: It is not possible as i know

Comment: @Jens is it alternatively possible to "collect" the prepared statements for `LOAD DATA INFILE`, so that I can send multiple prepared infile statements at once using `executeBatch()` or similar?

Comment: prepared Statements with `LOAD DATA INFILE` makes no sence. but you can use "normal"  Statements for that: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/